# Does postgresql index update on inserting new row?

Tags: insert, indexing, postgresql-9.2

Sorry if this is a dumb question but do i need to reindex my table every time i insert rows, or does the new row get indexed when added?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-intro.html)

> *Once an index is created, no further intervention is required: the system will update the index when the table is modified*

Comment: so surely by using a column that is history that will be updated a lot depending on what the user is doing that table will update the index (Even if the index isn't on the update column) 

surely a better practice would be put the update column in a table on its own with a user id relation so that the main focus of the user table is just on data that don't get updated very often and then there is a userupdate table which is more meaning full.

Answer (score 6):

http://postgresguide.com/performance/indexes.html

I think when you insert rows, the index does get updated. It maintains the sort on the index table as you insert data. Hence there are performance issues or downtimes on a table, if you try adding large number of rows at once.

Answer (score 3):

On top of the other answers: PostgreSQL is a top notch Relational Database. I'm not aware of **any** Relational Database system where indices are **not** updated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to depend on the type of index. For example, according to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/brin-intro.html, for BRIN indexes:

> When a new page is created that does not fall within the last summarized range, that range does not automatically acquire a summary tuple; those tuples remain unsummarized until a summarization run is invoked later, creating initial summaries. This process can be invoked manually using the brin_summarize_new_values(regclass) function, or automatically when VACUUM processes the table.

Although this seems to have changed in version 10.